# How to delete bidirectional many-to-many association

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

**Problem:**

I have **many-to-many association between** two entities **A and B**. 
I set **A entity** as an **owner of** their **relationship**(inverse=true is on A's collection in b.hbm.xml).

When i **delete an A entity**, corresponding **records in join table are deleted**.
When i **delete an B entity**, corresponding **records in join table are not deleted** (integrity violation exception).

--

Let's consider some very simple **example**:

```
class A{  
    Set<B> bset=new HashSet<B>();
    //...
}  

class B{  
    Set<A> aset=new HashSet<A>();  
    //...
}
```

File **a.hbm.xml** [m-to-m mappings only]:

```
<set name="bset" table="AB">  
    <key name="a_id"/>  
    <many-to-many column="b_id" class="B"/>  
</set>
```

File **b.hbm.xml** [m-to-m mappings only]:

```
<set name="aset" table="AB" inverse="true">  
    <key name="b_id"/>  
    <many-to-many column="a_id" class="A"/>  
</set>
```

Database **relations**:

```
A(id,...)  
B(id,...)  
AB(a_id,b_id)
```

Suppose that we have **some records in AB joint table**. For example:

> AB = {(1,1),(1,2)}

where AB= { (a_id , b_id) | ... ... }

--

**Situation 1** - works probably because A is owner of AB relationship:

```
A a=aDao.read(1);  //read A entity with id=1  
aDao.delete(a);    //delete 'a' entity and both relations with B-entities
```

**Situation 2** - doesn't work:

```
B b=bDao.read(1);   //read B entity with id=1  
bDao.delete(b);     //foreign key integrity violation
```

On the one hand, this is somehow logical to me, because the A entity is responsible for his relation with B.
But, on the other hand, it is not logical or at least it is not orm-like solution that I have to explicitly delete all records in join table where concrete B entity appears, and then to delete the B entity, as I show in situation 3:

**Situation 3** - works, but it is not 'elegant':

```
B b=bDao.read(1);  
Set<A> aset=b.getA();     //get set with A entities
Iterator i=aset.iterator();  

//while removes 'b' from all related A entities  
//while breaks relationships on A-side of relation (A is owner)
while(i.hasNext()){  
    A a=i.next();  
    a.bset.remove(b);   //remove entity 'b' from  related 'a' entity 
    aDao.update(a);       //key point!!! this line breaks relation in database
}  
bDao.delete(b);           //'b' is deleted because there is no related A-entities
```

--

**So, my question**: is there any more convenient way to delete no-owner entity (B in my example) in bidirectional many-to-many association and all of his many-to-many relations from joint table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate: delete many-to-many association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783602/hibernate-delete-many-to-many-association)

Comment: @Don Roby - i think that suggested topic is similar but i can't find answer to my problem. There, author wants to explicitly delete association. On the other side i want to delete association implicitly when i delete some of the entities that form association. Reason for my approach is 'implicit nature' of join table in m-to-m association.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not see what is not elegant about the code. It works fine in all cases and does not do any extra stuff which it is not supposed to. When I say A is owning side is a relationship AB, this would imply that creating or deleting the relationship lies in the hands of A. B has no say in the relationship. So if I want to move B somewhere else, A has to let go of B before B can be moved away. Hence, when choosing the owning side you should consider what you are going to do with the objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I just wanted to hear that. I'm beginner in Hibernate technology and i was not 100% sure in my understanding of problem, but now is ok.
When i mentioned elegant, i thought that maybe there is one-line-code solution for this kind of problem, because join table is in some sense implicit artifact, that is, i don't have possibility to explicitly delete rows from joint table itself. But explanation about owner stuff clarify things.