# Deleting entities with bidirectional ManyToMany - OneToMany

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have to classes that look like this:

**Content:**

```
public class Content {

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "content_id")
    @OrderBy("position")
    protected List<Links> links = new ArrayList<Links>();

    // some more fields and stuff

}
```

**Links:**

```
public class Links {

    // refers to content
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Content content;

    // some more fields and stuff

}
```

A content can have many links to other contents. A link links to a content and can belong to many contents.

When I'm trying to delete a content which is linked by links and those links are used in the content I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (KEYNAMEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) violated - child record found
```

The foreign key in the message is the primary key of the table `LINK`. The delete rule is `No Action`.

I'm using an Oracle Database and all tables are created by hibernate.

`orphanRemoval` is not working on the relation annotations.

**Edit:**

Here's a scetch, of what i'm trying to do
[image]

Comment: You should add mappedBy="links" to the relationship @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: why shoudl i do that? does this solve my problem?

Comment: Correct, but it properly specifies the owner of the relationship

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810689/hibernate-how-to-delete-bidirectional-many-to-many-association when they try to explain which way to use to delete a M2M relationship