# Hibernate - delete many-to-many association

Tags: java, database, hibernate, many-to-many

I have two tables/classes named book and author, which are connected through author_book join table and I need to delete row(s) from join table when changing authors of book or before deleting an author or book. I Have looked at the hibernate documentation but I can't figure out any way how to do it? Could someone show me an example of deleting association between book and author?

Comment: Please add the code you already have

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810689/how-to-delete-bidirectional-many-to-many-association

Answer (score 0):

in your author entity you can add this code

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Book> books;
```