# Delete Values from Join Table spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two tables students and subjects. A student can have more than one subject and vice versa. I have two model classes and vave joined using Many to Many relationship in spring boot and JPA.My problem is how I can delete values  from my join table. But I can't figure out how I can do delete from join table. For Student and Subject Model I delete comfortably using deleteById() function.This is my code:

```
          @ManyToMany
          @JoinTable(
          name = "student_subject", 
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"), 
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id"))
          private Set<SubjectModel> subjects;
```

//and my repository Class

```
          @Repository
          public interface SubjectDao extends JpaRepository<SubjectModel, Integer> {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the corresponding objects form both sides of the link, and then save them.

```
myStudent.getSubjects().remove(mySubject);
mySubject.getStudents().remove(myStudent);
SubjectDao subjectDao = new SubjectDao();
subjectDao.save(mySubject);
```

Here another examle: [Hibernate: delete many-to-many association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783602/hibernate-delete-many-to-many-association)

Answer (score 0):

You have two table Student and Subject.
And I suppose you want is delete one of the subject from a student.
For that you should let jpa delete the row from subject and student-subject association table. And dont need to user SubjectRepository.
Take a look.

```
Student firstStudent=studentRepository.findById(1);
Set<SubjectModel> subs=firstStudent.getSubject();
subs.clear();
firstStudent.setSubject(subs);

studentRepository.save(firstStudent);  // this method will delete the row from assiciation table as well as the subject table.
```